# Count entries in on specific month

Tags: mysql, database, count

I want to count the entries in my table in database in one month. For example total entries from January. I've tried this but it didnt worked out.

```
 SELECT MONTH(date1 = '$2015-01-01$') COUNT (*) COUNT from restowlist 
    WHERE MONTH(date1='$2015-01-01$')
```

Please help.

Comment: Surely `WHERE MONTH(date1)=1`?

Comment: What is the datatype of `date1`? Is it `DATE` or `DATETIME`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    restowlist
WHERE
    MONTH(yourDateColumn) = 1 AND YEAR(yourDateColumn) = 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select count(*) 
 from restowlist 
 where month(date1) = 1
 and year(date1) = 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM restowlist
WHERE DATEPART('year', datecolumn) = 2015
AND DATEPART('month', datecolumn) = 1
```

(apologies, as my syntax comes from SQL, rather than MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `restowlist` 
 WHERE `date1` BETWEEN cast('2016-01-01' as DATE) 
 AND cast('2016-01-31' as DATE);
```

Comment: The second datetime should be `2015-01-31 23:59:59`. Otherwise you'll ignore all the rows on that last day.